# How should $k$ items be selected in $m$ trials so that the average size of the intersection of selected items is as small as possible?

Tags: algorithms, extremal-combinatorics

Let $n$ be size of set of items and in $m$ trials $k$ items are selected from the set without replacement. In two different trials the same items can be selected. How should items be selected so that the number of items selected in two different trials have as few items in common as possible? I.e. let $T_x$ be the set of items selected in trial $x$, then select the items in each trial so that the sum of overlap between every pair of selections
$$
\sum_{1 \le i < j \le m} | T_i \cap T_j |
$$
is minimized. The order in which the items are picked doesn't matter, the only significant thing is whether or not the same item was picked in two different trials.

If $m \le \frac{n}{k}$ then the trivial answer is to select different items in each trial. And the maximizing the sum is easy as well $-$ simply select the same items in every trial.

In the interesting case where $m > \frac{n}{k}$ I think I have a solution but it is only a hunch and I'm unable to prove that the selection algorithm leads to a global minimum. The general idea is that you should attempt to share as few items as possible and attempt to avoid selecting the same set of items as was done in an earlier trial. For simplicity let's assume that $k \mid n$ so that $w=\frac{n}{k} \in \mathbb{N}$. It goes like this:

1. Trials are placed in groups of size $w$ such that each selected item during a trial is not found in any other trial in the same group.
2. There are $n!$ permutations for distributing the items over $w$ trials such that no item is shared between any two trials. Select items for the trials $T_{11}, T_{12}, \dots, T_{1w}$ in any way you want to form the first group $G_1$. The size of the intersection of any of these trial selections is zero.
3. It's now possible to create $w$ trials from the first one by selecting one item from $T_{11}$, one from $T_{12}$, and so on such that no item is shared among these trials. This forms the second group $G_2$, and trials in this group share one item which each trial of the first, i.e. $\forall a,b \,\,\,|T_{1a} \cap T_{2b}| = 1$, but none with items within the group $|T_{xa} \cap T_{xb}| = 0, a \ne b \wedge x \in \{1, 2\}$.
4. In fact, it's possible to create $k-1$ groups related to the first one such that each trial within a group share no items, but trials with the related groups share one item. Let us call these $k$ groups a family.

At this point it is possible to start from another permutation in step 2 and create $k$ related groups. These trials within a group share no items among each other, shares 1 item with each trial in the other groups in the family, but shares $0 - k$ items with trials in every group in the first family, and $\frac{k}{w}$ items on average with trials in other families.

Further families of items can be created until you've made $m$ trials in total. In the last family and group you form you want to choose the trials that share the fewest items with earlier trials.

If there are more trials $m$ than $n!$ repeat the above and make duplicates until you've got enough.

How would I go about to prove or disprove that this leads to a minimum? Is it sometimes better to form groups of items that share a few items? Is a brute force greedy algorithm going to end up with the same (or better) result? That make things simpler when $k \nmid m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a copy of an answer I wrote for a very similar question, ["How to generate balanced combinations"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2704432/how-to-generate-balanced-combinations/2858304#2858304)

### #

Yes, it is possible to sample the combinations in a manner that is very evenly balanced.

Point distributions that are more even than 'uniform random sampling' are called low discrepancy sequences (also called quasirandom sequences). See wikipedia article "[low discrepancy sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence)" for a brief overview on these sequences.  There are numerous ways to construct low discrepancy sequences, including Van der Corput/Halton, Kronecker/Weyl, Niederreiter, and Sobol to name a few. Furthermore, all of these can be used to create $d$-dimensional sequences.

The figure below shows a comparison of various low discrepancy sequences in two-dimensions. The important feature to note is how all of the distributions are more even than the random one, and have less 'gaps' and less 'clusters'.

[image]

The method below shows how we can exploit this evenness to select a sequences of subsets that are well balanced.

**Low Discrepancy Combinatorics**

However, for this particular question, we are not interested in point distributions in $n$-dimensional space, but rather subsets of $k$ items, each selected out of a population of $n$ objects. That is,

> Given a set of $n$ objects, $\{S: x_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n \} $ and an integer $k, \; (1\leq k \leq n)$,
>
> We show how to create an open sequence $\{s_0, s_1,s_2, s_3, \ldots \} $ of
>   subsets, each of size $k$, such that for all values of $m>1$ and $j \; (1 \leq j \leq k)$, the amongst first $m$ terms of the sequence, all possible $j$-tuples are distributed as evenly as possible.

That is, we show how to sample in a manner that at all times throughout the experiment, we maintain:

- similar frequencies of all possible $\{x_i\}$,
- similar frequencies of all possible 2-tuples of $\{x_i,x_j\}$;
- ...
- similar frequencies of all possible $k$-tuples.

Although the method below works with the use of any low discrepancy sequences it is only optimal for the Sobol and Niederreiter sequences due to their intrinsic relationship with binary sequences, and especially to a special characteristic that Sobol termed, [**"Property A"**](http://www.andreasaltelli.eu/file/repository/HD_SobolGenerator.pdf).

Thus, the method can be formally described as follows

**Methodology for constructing an even subset selection**

> 1. Let i=1.
> 2. Calculate the $i$-th term in the $n$-dimensional Sobol sequence
> 3. Convert this to a binary vector, $b_i$.
> 4. If $b_i$ has exactly $k$ ones in it, then this represents a subset that has exactly $k$ items, and so let this be the next subset; otherwise reject this $b_i$.
> 5. $i \leftarrow i+1$.
> 6. Goto step 2, until number of desired subsets is achieved.

In many cases, this method requires rejecting a modest fraction of subsets. However, as most computers can still typically scan through several million terms in under a second, an acceptance rate of only a few percent, is most likely not an issue for most people. In practice, this means that this method works well for situations where $d \lesssim 20$.

**An example**

To illustrate, we describe the how to select a few hundred samples, with each sample having exactly $k=4$ objects out of a possible $N=9$ objects. It should be clear from how this extends to arbitrary $n$ and $k$.

First we calculate the $n=9$-dimensional Sobol sequence. This is usually available via most statistical software libraries. Typically each software implementation varies slightly as there are various choices for key parameters that need to be made. Thus if your are trying to replicate this method, the values in the sequence that you construct may differ slightly, but the final results will still hold.

Using Mathematica, the first few terms of the $n=9$-dimensional Sobol sequence are:

$$ t_0 = (0.380, 0.462, 0.0743, 0.568, 0.933, 0.688, 0.304, 0.935, 0.867)$$
$$ t_1 = (0.880, 0.962, 0.574, 0.0679, 0.433, 0.188, 0.804, 0.435, 0.617)$$
$$ t_2 = (0.130, 0.712, 0.324, 0.318, 0.683, 0.438, 0.0537, 0.685, 0.117)$$
$$ t_3 = (0.630, 0.212, 0.824, 0.818, 0.183, 0.938, 0.554, 0.185, 0.0854)$$
$$ t_4 = (0.161, 0.368, 0.918, 0.662, 0.402, 0.0313, 0.772, 0.216, 0.585)$$
$$ t_5 = (0.661, 0.868, 0.418, 0.162, 0.902, 0.531, 0.272, 0.716, 0.835)$$
$$ t_6 = (0.411, 0.618, 0.668, 0.412, 0.152, 0.781, 0.522, 0.466, 0.335)$$
$$ t_7 = (0.911, 0.118, 0.168, 0.912, 0.652, 0.281, 0.0225, 0.966, 0.460)$$
$$ t_8 = (0.286, 0.993, 0.793, 0.287, 0.527, 0.156, 0.397, 0.0914, 0.960)$$
$$ t_9 = (0.786, 0.493, 0.293, 0.787, 0.0272, 0.656, 0.897, 0.591, 0.710)$$
$$ t_{10} = (0.036,0.243,0.543,0.537,0.777,0.906,0.147,0.341,0.210)$$
$$ \ldots $$

Now convert each of the components in each term, into a binary $0/1$ value via the Round[.] function.  This, results in the following sequence 
$$ b_0 = (0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1)$$
$$ b_1 = (1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1)$$
$$ b_2 = (0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0)$$
$$ b_3 = (1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0)$$
$$ b_4 = (0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)$$
$$ b_5 = (1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1)$$
$$ b_6 = (0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0)$$
$$ b_7 = (1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0)$$
$$ b_8 = (0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1)$$
$$ b_9 = (1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1)$$
$$ b_{10} = (0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)$$
$$ \ldots$$

The key part of the method now is to understand that each of the binary vectors defines a subset. For example the first term  $ b_0 = (0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1)$, corresponds to selecting only the 4th, 5th, 6th, 8th and 9th (reading from left to right).

That is, the subset {DEFHI} if the objects were the letters of the alphabet. However, this subset has five items not 4, so reject this sample. Similarly for $b_1,b_2,b_3$ and $b_4$.

However, $ b_4 = (0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)$ corresponds to $\{CDGI\}$ which has the exactly the prescribed number of items, so this accept this as the first sample.

Thus the first few (accepted) terms are: $\{b_4,b_6,b_7,b_8,...\} $
$$=  \{ CDGI, BCFG, ADEH, BCEI, CDEF, ABGH, DFGI, BEFI, BDHI, EGHI,... \}$$

If we follow this method for our particular case of $n=9,k=4$, the first $m=2000$ terms of the Sobol sequence will result in 489 acceptable subsets of length $k=4$.

**Empirical Results**

We can verify that for our example, this produces evenly combinations by listing the frequency counts for various tuples.

The sorted frequency of each of the 11 different $x_i$ is,
$$ 218, 218, 218, 218, 218, 219, 219, 219, 221$$

The sorted frequency of each of the 36 different pairs $\{x_i,x_j\}$ is,
$$ 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 
82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 
83, 84$$

The sorted frequency of each of the 84 different triplets $\{x_i,x_j,x_k\}$
$$ 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, \
23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, \
23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, \
24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, \
24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24$$

And finally, the sorted frequency of each of the 126 different 4-tuples is:
$$3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, \
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, \
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, \
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, \
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, \
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
$$

**Special values of $m$**

The beautiful characteristic of Sobol sequences (more precisely Property A sequences) is that for all multiples of $2^d = 512$ terms, the above subset frequency counts will be exactly even, as each $j$-tuple will occur exactly $\binom{n-j}{k-j}$ times.

That is, if we had the freedom to **select a fixed $m$ in advance** then choosing $m=512$, (which would result in $\binom{n}{k}$ accepted terms) would then be the obvious ideal choice.

However, the main contribution of this post, is to show that this method produces excellent results for arbitrary values of $m$. Said another way, this method describes how to construct an open-ended sequence that produces very even $j$-tuple frequency distributions for all $(1\leq k\leq n$), **for all** values of $m=1,2,3,.....$ .

**Comparison with Uniform Random Sampling**

Obviously these frequency counts are very even. However, to show how much this is an improvement over simple uniform random sample, the follow frequency counts are given for a corresponding sample of 490 randomly sampled 4-tuples.

The frequency of each of the 9 different $x_i$ is,
$$196, 196, 200, 208, 216, 220, 224, 225, 235$$

The frequency of each of the 36 different pairs $\{x_i,x_j\}$ is,
$$ 66, 67, 70, 70, 70, 71, 72, 72, 72, 73, 73, 74, 74, 75, 75, 76, 77, \
78, 78, 79, 80, 82, 84, 85, 85, 86, 86, 88, 89, 90, 90, 91, 92, 93, \
96, 101$$

The frequency of each of 84 the different triplets $\{x_i,x_j,x_k\}$
$$ 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, \
19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, \
21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, \
24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, \
27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 36$$

And finally, the frequency of each of the 126 different 4-tuples is:
$$0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, \
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, \
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, \
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, \
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, \
7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10
$$

**Summary**

The low discrepancy Sobol sequence can be used to construct a sequence of subsets such that the cumulative frequency of all possible subsets of variables is evenly distributed.